# Something is wrong with my graphic card

Tags: gaming

After couple of minutes when I play a heavy games (Like BF4, WarThunder...) The game is starting to get like messy.. I recorded how it looks like:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=19d4SuzUOlk

This is the DxDiag: http://pastebin.com/E4CE7yyE

What can cause this problem?

Comment: Not sure what you're referring to.  Can you describe what, exactly, is the unsatisfactory performance?

Comment: @fixer1234 as u can see in the video, the game starts twitching and It's not pretty much comfort to play like this and neither fun..

Answer (score 1):

Check the obvious things:

> Driver Date/Size: 4/18/2014 05:42:54

Update driver - http://support.amd.com/en-us/download

Check card for dust build up. Card isn't that old so this is unlikely, but ensure fan is working and memory is not overheating.

Comment: Well, now It's much better but it's still messy :X